# Local flink execution has incredibly low performance

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm currently porting some algorithms of my company to a flink application to be run as streams in future. To test those algorithms I'm using existing data which I'm reading from a CSV file and then use [flink-spector](https://github.com/ottogroup/flink-spector) to create streams. Those datasets usually hold around 10.000 datums while each datum contains a timestamp and an integer value.

My problem now is that the flink application takes extremly long (around half an hour) to process this data which should be easily doable in a couple of seconds and I can't figure out why.

This is how my code looks:

```
public class MyAlgorithmTest extends DataStreamTestBase {

    @Test
    public void testMyAlgorithm() {

        DataStreamSource<MyData> myDataStream = 
            createTestStream(getEventTimeInputBuilder("MyData.csv"));

        DataStream<MyData> avgDataStream = myDataStream
            .keyBy(value -> value.getUniqueId())
            .window(SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(1), Time.seconds(30)))
            // aggregate data over windows of one minute
            .apply(new MyDataAggregator())
            .keyBy(value -> value.getUniqueId())
            .window(SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(5), Time.seconds(150)))
            // calculate the moving average over windows of five minutes
            .apply(new MovingAvgWindowFunction<>());
        }
    }
```

The jobs are successfully deployed locally (can't post the full output here unfortunately). This is a part of my output in the first couple of seconds:

```
11:38:22,138 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionClientActor      - Job cd666d998a392d0907d5522babc80342 was successfully submitted to the JobManager akka://flink/deadLetters.
11:38:22,139 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                - Scheduling job cd666d998a392d0907d5522babc80342 (Flink Streaming Job).
11:38:22,139 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Job Flink Streaming Job (cd666d998a392d0907d5522babc80342) switched from state CREATED to RUNNING.
11:38:22,142 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Source: Collection Source (1/1) (712aa1b16f98f6a44ec52c60ed920a1c) switched from CREATED to SCHEDULED.
11:38:22,146 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionClientActor      - 09/21/2017 11:38:22  Job execution switched to status RUNNING.
11:38:22,147 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionClientActor      - 09/21/2017 11:38:22  Source: Collection Source(1/1) switched to SCHEDULED 
11:38:22,155 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(60000, 30000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@44ebb3d8}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124)) (1/1) (debbe699a15106b9ef91ad4916a6ab5d) switched from CREATED to SCHEDULED.
11:38:22,156 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionClientActor      - 09/21/2017 11:38:22  TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(60000, 30000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@44ebb3d8}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124))(1/1) switched to SCHEDULED 
11:38:22,157 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(300000, 150000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@21ca5b67}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124)) (1/1) (f168bd42f08204cc049673ab2985b4f0) switched from CREATED to SCHEDULED.
11:38:22,158 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionClientActor      - 09/21/2017 11:38:22  TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(300000, 150000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@21ca5b67}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124))(1/1) switched to SCHEDULED 
11:38:22,164 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Source: Collection Source (1/1) (712aa1b16f98f6a44ec52c60ed920a1c) switched from SCHEDULED to DEPLOYING.
11:38:22,165 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Deploying Source: Collection Source (1/1) (attempt #0) to 
11:38:22,178 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionClientActor      - 09/21/2017 11:38:22  Source: Collection Source(1/1) switched to DEPLOYING 
11:38:22,187 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(60000, 30000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@44ebb3d8}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124)) (1/1) (debbe699a15106b9ef91ad4916a6ab5d) switched from SCHEDULED to DEPLOYING.
11:38:22,189 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionClientActor      - 09/21/2017 11:38:22  TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(60000, 30000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@44ebb3d8}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124))(1/1) switched to DEPLOYING 
11:38:22,189 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Deploying TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(60000, 30000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@44ebb3d8}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124)) (1/1) (attempt #0) to 
11:38:22,265 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(300000, 150000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@21ca5b67}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124)) (1/1) (f168bd42f08204cc049673ab2985b4f0) switched from SCHEDULED to DEPLOYING.
11:38:22,268 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Deploying TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(300000, 150000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@21ca5b67}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124)) (1/1) (attempt #0) to 
11:38:22,269 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionClientActor      - 09/21/2017 11:38:22  TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(300000, 150000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@21ca5b67}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124))(1/1) switched to DEPLOYING 
11:38:22,312 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Received task Source: Collection Source (1/1)
11:38:22,313 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Source: Collection Source (1/1) (712aa1b16f98f6a44ec52c60ed920a1c) switched from CREATED to DEPLOYING.
11:38:22,314 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Creating FileSystem stream leak safety net for task Source: Collection Source (1/1) (712aa1b16f98f6a44ec52c60ed920a1c) [DEPLOYING]
11:38:22,321 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Loading JAR files for task Source: Collection Source (1/1) (712aa1b16f98f6a44ec52c60ed920a1c) [DEPLOYING].
11:38:22,328 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Received task TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(60000, 30000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@44ebb3d8}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124)) (1/1)
11:38:22,331 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(60000, 30000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@44ebb3d8}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124)) (1/1) (debbe699a15106b9ef91ad4916a6ab5d) switched from CREATED to DEPLOYING.
11:38:22,331 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Creating FileSystem stream leak safety net for task TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(60000, 30000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@44ebb3d8}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124)) (1/1) (debbe699a15106b9ef91ad4916a6ab5d) [DEPLOYING]
11:38:22,332 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Loading JAR files for task TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(60000, 30000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@44ebb3d8}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124)) (1/1) (debbe699a15106b9ef91ad4916a6ab5d) [DEPLOYING].
11:38:22,333 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Registering task at network: Source: Collection Source (1/1) (712aa1b16f98f6a44ec52c60ed920a1c) [DEPLOYING].
11:38:22,337 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Received task TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(300000, 150000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@21ca5b67}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124)) (1/1)
11:38:22,336 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Registering task at network: TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(60000, 30000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@44ebb3d8}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124)) (1/1) (debbe699a15106b9ef91ad4916a6ab5d) [DEPLOYING].
11:38:22,346 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(300000, 150000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@21ca5b67}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124)) (1/1) (f168bd42f08204cc049673ab2985b4f0) switched from CREATED to DEPLOYING.
11:38:22,349 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Creating FileSystem stream leak safety net for task TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(300000, 150000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@21ca5b67}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124)) (1/1) (f168bd42f08204cc049673ab2985b4f0) [DEPLOYING]
11:38:22,349 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Loading JAR files for task TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(300000, 150000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@21ca5b67}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124)) (1/1) (f168bd42f08204cc049673ab2985b4f0) [DEPLOYING].
11:38:22,351 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Registering task at network: TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(300000, 150000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@21ca5b67}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124)) (1/1) (f168bd42f08204cc049673ab2985b4f0) [DEPLOYING].
11:38:22,364 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(60000, 30000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@44ebb3d8}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124)) (1/1) (debbe699a15106b9ef91ad4916a6ab5d) switched from DEPLOYING to RUNNING.
11:38:22,366 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Source: Collection Source (1/1) (712aa1b16f98f6a44ec52c60ed920a1c) switched from DEPLOYING to RUNNING.
11:38:22,366 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(300000, 150000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@21ca5b67}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124)) (1/1) (f168bd42f08204cc049673ab2985b4f0) switched from DEPLOYING to RUNNING.
11:38:22,371 INFO  org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask           - No state backend has been configured, using default state backend (Memory / JobManager)
11:38:22,386 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(60000, 30000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@44ebb3d8}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124)) (1/1) (debbe699a15106b9ef91ad4916a6ab5d) switched from DEPLOYING to RUNNING.
11:38:22,386 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionClientActor      - 09/21/2017 11:38:22  TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(60000, 30000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@44ebb3d8}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124))(1/1) switched to RUNNING 
11:38:22,377 INFO  org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask           - No state backend has been configured, using default state backend (Memory / JobManager)
11:38:22,389 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(300000, 150000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@21ca5b67}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124)) (1/1) (f168bd42f08204cc049673ab2985b4f0) switched from DEPLOYING to RUNNING.
11:38:22,390 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionClientActor      - 09/21/2017 11:38:22  TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(300000, 150000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@21ca5b67}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124))(1/1) switched to RUNNING 
11:38:22,395 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Source: Collection Source (1/1) (712aa1b16f98f6a44ec52c60ed920a1c) switched from DEPLOYING to RUNNING.
11:38:22,395 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionClientActor      - 09/21/2017 11:38:22  Source: Collection Source(1/1) switched to RUNNING 
11:38:22,377 INFO  org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask           - No state backend has been configured, using default state backend (Memory / JobManager)
11:38:22,458 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapKeyedStateBackend     - Initializing heap keyed state backend with stream factory.
11:38:22,469 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapKeyedStateBackend     - Initializing heap keyed state backend with stream factory.
```

After this there's no output for the next half an hour while my CPU is fully utilized. I'm logging each call to `MyDataAggregator` or `MovingAvgWindowFunction` to see how long they take so after half an hour those logs come in:

```
12:09:06,106 INFO  com.myapplication      - MyDataAggregator
12:09:06,106 INFO  com.myapplication      - MyDataAggregator
12:09:06,106 INFO  com.myapplication      - MyDataAggregator
12:09:06,106 INFO  com.myapplication      - MovingAvgWindowFunction
12:09:06,107 INFO  com.myapplication      - MovingAvgWindowFunction
12:09:06,107 INFO  com.myapplication      - MyDataAggregator
...
```

And then the jobs are done:

```
12:09:07,739 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(300000, 150000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@21ca5b67}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124)) (1/1) (f168bd42f08204cc049673ab2985b4f0) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
12:09:07,739 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Freeing task resources for TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(300000, 150000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@21ca5b67}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124)) (1/1) (f168bd42f08204cc049673ab2985b4f0).
12:09:07,740 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Ensuring all FileSystem streams are closed for task TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(300000, 150000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@21ca5b67}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124)) (1/1) (f168bd42f08204cc049673ab2985b4f0) [FINISHED]
12:09:07,741 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Un-registering task and sending final execution state FINISHED to JobManager for task TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(300000, 150000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@21ca5b67}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124)) (f168bd42f08204cc049673ab2985b4f0)
12:09:07,741 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(300000, 150000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@21ca5b67}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124)) (1/1) (f168bd42f08204cc049673ab2985b4f0) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
12:09:07,741 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionClientActor      - 09/21/2017 12:09:07  TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(300000, 150000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@21ca5b67}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124))(1/1) switched to FINISHED 
12:09:07,744 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(60000, 30000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@44ebb3d8}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124)) (1/1) (debbe699a15106b9ef91ad4916a6ab5d) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
12:09:07,744 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Freeing task resources for TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(60000, 30000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@44ebb3d8}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124)) (1/1) (debbe699a15106b9ef91ad4916a6ab5d).
12:09:07,745 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Ensuring all FileSystem streams are closed for task TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(60000, 30000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@44ebb3d8}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124)) (1/1) (debbe699a15106b9ef91ad4916a6ab5d) [FINISHED]
12:09:07,756 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Un-registering task and sending final execution state FINISHED to JobManager for task TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(60000, 30000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@44ebb3d8}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124)) (debbe699a15106b9ef91ad4916a6ab5d)
12:09:07,759 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(60000, 30000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@44ebb3d8}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124)) (1/1) (debbe699a15106b9ef91ad4916a6ab5d) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
12:09:07,759 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Job Flink Streaming Job (cd666d998a392d0907d5522babc80342) switched from state RUNNING to FINISHED.
12:09:07,759 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator     - Stopping checkpoint coordinator for job cd666d998a392d0907d5522babc80342
12:09:07,759 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionClientActor      - 09/21/2017 12:09:07  TriggerWindow(SlidingEventTimeWindows(60000, 30000), ListStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@44ebb3d8}, EventTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.apply(WindowedStream.java:1124))(1/1) switched to FINISHED 
12:09:07,759 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionClientActor      - 09/21/2017 12:09:07  Job execution switched to status FINISHED.
12:09:07,760 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.StandaloneCompletedCheckpointStore  - Shutting down
12:09:07,771 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionClientActor      - Terminate JobClientActor.
12:09:07,771 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobClient                     - Job execution complete
12:09:07,772 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionClientActor      - Disconnect from JobManager Actor[akka://flink/user/jobmanager_1#-1402375298].
```

This is really strange as there's just no output at all for half an hour. Does anybody has an idea what flink might be doing in that time?

I know that the local execution environment isn't optimized, but even with 10k values, neither windowing, keying nor my simple aggregation + average calculation should take that long. The bottleneck definitely seems to be the CPU which is fully utilized the whole time. I've given the application 2GB of RAM and i/o doesn't seem to be a problem, my disk isn't really utilized at all.

Edit: I've played a little bit with those datasets. If I reduce the 10k dataset to only 5k, the execution time drops from half an hour to 4 minutes. This is really weired as one would expect linear growth at maximum.

Comment: Rampant speculation:  I wonder if this has something to do with event time.   The watermark must progress to keep the pipeline moving, and in your case reaching the end-of-file (which causes a watermark of MAX_VALUE) might be part of the story.   Please clarify, is the job using event time and are you using a watermark assigner?

Comment: To check what @EronWright mentioned above, can you change the event time based sliding windows to processing time based sliding windows(SlidingProcessingTimeWindows)? Just to see whether it works otherwise or not?

Comment: Can you attach a profiler to Flink to understand what is eating up all those CPU cycles for 30 minutes?
Flink should be able to process this data in almost no time.

Comment: @EronWright Yes, my job is using event time. I do not use a watermark assigner, as the `EventTimeInputBuilder` from flink-spector creates a flink source that uses `collectWithTimestamp(T element, long timestamp)` to collect the elements. And yes, a MAX_VALUE timestamp is being collected as last element. [This](https://github.com/ottogroup/flink-spector/wiki/Defining-Input#using-eventtimeinputbuilder) is how the input is generated.

Comment: @BiplobBiswas Using processing time windows doesn't change anything at all. However, if I use the `InputBuilder` instead of the `EventTimeInputBuilder` of `flink-spector` it runs really fast. So there has to be some issue with windowing.

Comment: @RobertMetzger Thanks I think that solved the problem. The issue seems to be `org.flinkspector.datastream.util.InputUtil#produceWatermarks` which uses poorly performing recursion.

Comment: Cool! Good to hear that you've figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

I would attach a profiler to Flink to understand what is eating up all those CPU cycles for 30 minutes.

Flink should be able to process this data in almost no time.